Lightning-base-components deprecated
The NPM package of "lightning-base-components" seems to have been deprecated. Do anybody know why and whether we can expect it to become available again later?
We have several project where we utilize Storybook to showcase custom components that is using lightning-base-components internally. This whole setup is now at risk due to the deprecation of the NPM package.
The source code is no longer available as well, at least i can't find it
See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components

I guess this has to be seen in the context of archiving the base component recipes, although over there Salesforce explicitly recommends to use the npm package instead.

I've asked a closely related question on 11 July 2024 in the LWC Trailblazer Community group, but haven't received any feedback from Salesforce so far.
